# Can I count elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, count

I have a list in a `ul` that is in an ASP repeater. The list is set to overflow with a scrollbar and to only show 16 `li`s at a time. Is there a jQuery count function that I can use that would allow me to select every "16th" `li` and add a specific class to it?

Selecting the last one won't work because the 16th `div` is not the last `div` since it is in a repeater.

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is, it's called [:nth-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild).

Sample:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(16n)").addClass("sixteenth");
```

Comment: Right, I understand that. But I want to get the "16th","32", etc...Would this function do that?

Comment: I've modified it, yes it will. Just change (16) to (16n).

Comment: Does this apply the selection rules with jQ or with the browser?  I've noticed nth-child is not supported by FF3.  If jQ is doing it by itself then there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `.each` function:

```
$("ul li").each(function(index, domEle) {
    if (index%16==0) {
          $(domEle).addClass("CLASS_NAME");
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this option a bit heavy-handed? jQuery already supplies the ability to do what he wants *without* iterating over the entire list! See my answer for an example of the nth-child selector.

Comment: it works, though. your solution is, how you say, eleganter, tho :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply class to every element after 16<sup>th</sup> then you can use **[:gt(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index)** selector.

```
$("ul li:gt(16)").addClass("CLASS_NAME");
```

remember :gt, :lt etc selectors use zero based index.

for every 16<sup>th</sup> ofcouse you can use **[:nth-child(index)](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index)**

```
$("ul li:nth-child(16)").addClass("CLASS_NAME");
```

remember *:nth-child* based selectors use 1 for first element.

Comment: well this method ":nth-child(index)" will only select the 16th li. I need it to then grab the 32nd, 48th,.....

Comment: Yes and for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181113/can-i-count-elements-using-jquery/1181187#1181187 will work!!

Comment: So will http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181113/can-i-count-elements-using-jquery/1181114#1181114 - but with far less code  :)

Comment: sure @Jason only you edited it after I've posted the comment!